# Where are hvm kernel and initrd for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to install ubuntu kvm's and I can't find the hvm kernel and initrd images. Where are they? I've downloaded the desktop iso, live server and focal-live-server iso and it's not on any of them.I remember these were hard to find before. Why is this stuff just not on the iso image?

Answer (score 0):

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/focal-legacy-server-.iso

It appears to be here. And here's some extra characters so the answer will take. 8-)